# When setting the debug path eclipse says source not found

Tags: eclipse

I use Eclipse Version: Luna Release (4.4.0) and i imported my projects as maven project. When i do remote debugging, it tries to look a class, and asking "Edit source lookup path". I tried both "workspace folder" and "java project" options and add them in the debug path. But eclipse says "Source not found." and again and again asking me to set the path for source.

I did same in my older eclipse versions(ganymade/galilio) and was ale to debug my project successfully.

What is the issue in the newer Luna version?